Solve the ODE $y(x+y)dx+(1+xy)dy=0$
I need to solve the following ODE:
$$y(x+y)dx+(1+xy)dy=0$$
I can see that this is not an exact equation, and when I tried to multiply it by the integration factor $\mu(x)$ or $\mu(y)$ I got nothing.
So I started to "play" with it.
$$y(x+y)dx+(1+xy)dy=0$$
$$y(x+y)+(1+xy)y'=0$$
$$y'=-\frac{yx+y^2}{1+xy}=-\left( \frac{xy+1+y^2-1}{1+xy} \right)=-\left(1+\frac{y^2-1}{1+xy}\right)$$
What can I do from here?

Hint. $\mu(y)=\frac{1}{y}$ is an integrating factor.

Dividing the ODE $y(x+y)+(1+xy)y'=0$ by $y$, we obtain
$$
x+y+\frac{y'}{y}+xy'=0 \implies x+\frac{y'}{y}+(xy)'=0
\implies \frac{x^2}{2}+\ln|y|+xy=C.
$$

Starting from @Gonçalo's answer
$$y=\frac 1 x\, W\left(-c \,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Hint.
Making $y = \frac ux$ we have
$$
\frac{u'}{u}(1+u)=\frac{1-x^2}{x}
$$
which is separable, giving
$$
\ln u + u = \ln x -\frac{x^2}{2}+ c_0
$$
and finally
$$
u = W\left(x e^{c_0-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)
$$
with $W(\cdot)$ the Lambert function.
